# Giving different id to each marker "overlay" at google maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, overlays

I want each marker on the map (Map View) with different id so that I can remove it or change its icon dynamically at run time.

How do we achieve that ?

Also please I want the best way to add many markers on the map without making it slow when moving it on taping over it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do we achieve that ?

Subclass `OverlayItem` and store whatever you want in it, using that instead of the ordinary `OverlayItem` class for your items. For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk) has a `CustomItem` subclass of `OverlayItem` that, among other things, draws different icons at runtime.

> Also please I want the best way to add many markers on the map without making it slow when moving it on taping over it

Don't "add many markers" to an `ItemizedOverlay`, to the point where it is "when moving it on taping over it". `ItemizedOverlay` is designed for small numbers of items.

If you need lots of items, you will most likely need to create your own `Overlay`, where you can have more smarts about which subset of your items will be relevant at any given time.

Comment: so to achieve the speed issue and different ids together , should I extend overlay? If yes, do u have any sample projects or supported links ?. Thank you so much.